# How to read local php file from java gui program (not from web)?

Tags: java, file, inputstream

this is my php code checker code for java application but i want to scan a new file in my java GUI program...

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
            URL u = new URL("http://www.example.com/my/php/doc.php");
            URLConnection c = u.openConnection();
            InputStream r = c.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(r));
            for (String line;
                (
                    line = reader.
                    `enter code here`
                    readLine()) != null;
            )
            System.out.println(line);
```

This code opens file from the web but I want to open file from the desktop

Comment: You first might want to correctly format / formulate your question. In the current version nobody would want to read that code.

Comment: this code open the web php file but i want to open my file from desktop

Comment: I don't even understand what you are talking about. Nothing in this makes sense.

Comment: this code read data from a file in an URL manner but i want to convert it into desktop meanwhile i want to open a file from my desktop..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use: `new File(your_path).toURI().toURL();`

i.e.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    URL u = new File("E:\\test_data_014.lst").toURI().toURL();
    URLConnection c = u.openConnection();
    InputStream r = c.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(r));
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    reader.close();
}
```

}

Comment: where i paste it tell me please

Comment: public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
  URL u = new File("E:\\test_data_014.lst").toURI().toURL();
  URLConnection c = u.openConnection();
  InputStream r = c.getInputStream();
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(r));
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
  String line;
  while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
  }
  reader.close();
 }
}

Comment: @Akceptop u didnot get what im trying to ask...listen i made a application on java which can open and then scan the code of php and give output it tells syntax errors and what errors in php code...what you send me it just display the program i run...

Comment: Yes, sure it just displays the content of file. I thought you have already implemented the parsing logic and just need to understand how to read data from a file in an URL manner. So you just need to place your parsing logic instead of that System.out line

Comment: Sorry I just don't understand what exactly you want. Do you have an application parsing php code already?

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes available in the java.io package to read from files. For e.g like this:

```
public class TextFileReadingExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\MyUsername\\Desktop\\MyFile.txt");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

        String line;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```